# Laravel 5.1: Controller use variable from method [Get]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have code in route.php

```
Route::get('website/{post}/{comment}', ['uses'=>'MainController@add']);
```

In file MainController:

```
public function add(Requests $request){
    $data = $request->all();
    echo $data['post'];
    echo $data['comment'];
}
```

Can i do like this? If i can, help me fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: Are `post` and `comment` fields in your form?

Comment: no, just use url: `http://mydomain/[something]/[something]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation on [controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#basic-controllers).

Your controller code should look like this:

```
public function add($post, $comment){
    echo $post;
    echo $comment;
}
```